# $2^n-1$ divides $2^{(m-1)!}-1$ if $n$ divides $(m-1)!$

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $m$ is an even positive integer and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ divides $(m-1)!$. It is said that then $2^n -1$ divides $2^{(m-1)!} - 1$. I expect this claim to be easy provable because there is no comment in my book. Still, I couldn't show it. Can you give me a hint please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that $r\mid s$ implies that the polynomial $X^r-1$ divides $X^s-1$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We have $(m-1)!=nk$ for some $k$ therefore $2^{(m-1)!}-1=2^{nk}-1=(2^{n})^k-1=(2^n - 1)((2^{n})^{k-1} + (2^{n})^{k-2} + .. + 1)$

I used the identity $a^n - b^n =(a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + .. + b^{n-1})$